# Color for my website design

Tags: html, css, colors

- Please check the link..
  [sample site](http://www.housecreative.co.uk/work.html)

  I want to know the name of green color present in the above site. i need to use it for my design. please some one help me.

Comment: do you work with OSX?

Comment: The header is a gradient from #63BAB0 to #59A79E.

Comment: #63bab0 -- use inspect element in firebug/chrome

Comment: you can use icp or firebug or inspect element in chrome whats the problem ?

Comment: am a beginner to website design.. now i learned how to use colorzilla etc.. thanks for all your answers and comments and for down vote as well.

Comment: you could try [graphic design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) it's a version of stackoverflow specifically for queries like yours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look @ view source

```
.banner-wrap {
text-align: center;
background-color: #63bab0;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #63bab0, #59a79e);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #63bab0, #59a79e);
padding: 0 0 1em 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Install colorzilla to your browser, it helps to pick the colors

**http://www.colorzilla.com/chrome/**

Answer (score 0):

It's in the source:

```
.banner-wrap {
    background-color: hsl(173, 39%, 56%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

many way to know some of this is use `photoshop` then use `color picker` and if your browser is Firefox use [ColorZilla](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/colorzilla/) Add on

```
#60b4ab
```

hope this help

Answer (score 0):

here is the css

```
    background-color: #63bab0;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #63bab0, #59a79e); 
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #63bab0, #59a79e);
```

Answer (score 0):

Developer has used flat color as `63BAB0`

And then if gradient is supported (incase audience is on mozilla or [webkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) based browsers) then he opts for slight gradience from `63BAB0` to `59A79E`

In terms of **CSS**:
`background-color: #63BAB0;`
`background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #63BAB0, #59A79E);`
`background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #63bab0, #59a79e);`

You can play around with this color on 
http://www.colorhexa.com/59a79e

Hope it helps!